# Options not being added to a class which inherits from Command

Tags: c#, .net-core, command-line, system.commandline

I'm making a console app targeting dotnet core, using Microsofts **System.CommandLine** namespaces to parse commands.
I know these namespaces are in beta and alpha stages, nothing is production here.

**My package references, and versions**

```
    <ProjectReference Include="..\lib\lib.csproj" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.CommandLine.DragonFruit" Version="0.4.0-alpha.22272.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.CommandLine.Rendering" Version="0.4.0-alpha.22272.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.CommandLine" Version="2.0.0-beta4.22272.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.CommandLine.NamingConventionBinder" Version="2.0.0-beta4.22272.1" />
```

Can anybody **explain why it is the separated code doesn't work while the code nested in Main does?** I'm assuming there's something happening (or rather not happening) when i try to implement this in the constructor that I can't see or don't understand but I can't for the life of me figure it out. Surely I'm not expected to assemble all the commands like that but between GPT, google and the official docs (very out of date) I'm stuck.

Criticism is welcome, I'm still learning.

**My issue** is when separating my Commands into classes, and adding all Options and Arguments from the constructor like so

```cs
public class RootCommand : Command
{
    public RootCommand()
        : base("cli", "WTNS root command.")
    {
        
        // all the options, args and initialization
        
        var executeOption = new Option<bool>(["--execute", "-e"],"If this option is set to true the request will be processed without starting the REPL.");
        executeOption.SetDefaultValue(true);
        AddOption(executeOption);
        
        Handler = CommandHandler.Create<bool>((option) => {
            if(!option)
            {
                Repl.Instance.Listen();
            } else
            {
                // Check
                Debug.Print($"###  success  ###");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

and invoking the command from Main()

```cs
public sealed class Cli
{
    public static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var rootCommand = new RootCommand();

        var parser = new CommandLineBuilder(rootCommand).UseDefaults().Build();
        parser.Invoke(args);

        Debug.Print("Command Name: " + rootCommand.Name);
        foreach (Option o in rootCommand.Options)
        {
            Debug.Print("Option: " + o.Name);
        }
    }
}
```

and running the project

```
dotnet run --execute true
```

I get the output

```cs
Unrecognized command or argument '--execute'.
Unrecognized command or argument 'true'.

Description:

Usage:
  cli [options]

Options:
  --version       Show version information
  -?, -h, --help  Show help and usage information

Command Name: cli
Option: version
Option: help
```

Where you can see it did not recognize the command as I expected (and by extension didn't invoke the Handler either).

However, this code, where the Option is added in Main() **does** work as expected and **does** invoke the Handler

```cs
public sealed class Cli
{
    public static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var rootCommand = new RootCommand();

        var option = new Option<bool>(["--execute", "-e"],"If this option is set to true the request will be processed without starting the REPL.");
        rootCommand.AddOption(option);

        rootCommand.Handler = CommandHandler.Create<bool>(async (execute) =>
        {
            if(true)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("option was true");
            }
        });

        var parser = new CommandLineBuilder(rootCommand).UseDefaults().Build();
        parser.Invoke(args);

        foreach (Option o in rootCommand.Options)
        {
            Debug.Print("Option :" + o.Name);
        }
    }
}
```

yielding the following output

```
option was true
Option : execute
Option : version
Option : help
```

---

**EDIT:** (Steve Wong)

**Breakpoints**

[First Breakpoint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tSijS.png) **Before** `rootCommand` is initialized

[Second Breakpoint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZTdE1.png) **As** `rootCommand` is initialized. At this point, the constructor should have been called, and `rootCommand.Handler` should have been set, but it remains `null` as seen in the photo.

[Third Breakpoint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d7o9q.png) **After** `rootCommand` has been initialized.

Note that I haven't changed the code within the constructor (aside from a few changed comments) of `RootCommand`. The constructor still reads

```cs
public class RootCommand : Command
{
    public RootCommand()
        : base("cli", "WTNS root command.")
    {
        var executeOption = new Option<bool>(["--execute", "-e"],"If this option is set to true the request will be processed without starting the REPL.");
        executeOption.SetDefaultValue(true);

        AddOption(executeOption);
        
        Handler = CommandHandler.Create<bool>((option) => {
            if(!option)
            {
                // TODO: Send the command to the REPL
                Repl.Instance.Listen();
            } else
            {
                // TODO: Parse Command
                Console.WriteLine("#### Executing command ####");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**EDIT 2:**

I've provided a video where you can see I attempt to set breakpoints within the constructor of `RootCommand` It seems my breakpoints never get called no matter what. The code just runs as normal and closes when my only breakpoints are within `RootCommand(){}`. Despite the `Option<bool>` field containing a value, meaning the constructor must have ran.

I'm not a very experienced debugger but you can also see when i set a single breakpoint in CLI and the rest in RootCommand, all breakpoints in RootCommand go gray when i strart debugging and say `No symbols loaded for this document` Which seems odd I haven't stripped any symbols or compiled as release.

One more thing, the argument `--execute` is being passed from `launch.json`, that's why you don't see me typing it, it's there though.

[Here's the clip of me setting some breakpoints](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tInNrJP-lSU&ab_channel=CRT.SOLUBLE)

And if this helps, [here's a cleaned copy of my entire project](https://1drv.ms/u/s!Aj46CUe-Tv1plN59qQ2EUnS0Vt8pwg?e=zeyfB0) (OneDrive link).

Comment: I am not able to reproduce the error where `--execute` is not recognized.  The first approach with `RootCommand` adding options in the constructor appears to work fine. I believe the code is correct.  I can't think of other differences that would give you those results.

Comment: Hi Steve, thank you for taking a look. Can you provide the dotnet core version you are using as well as the version number for System.CommandLine? I'm running 2.0.0-beta4.22272.1 and targeting net8. Just wanna check all my bases.

Comment: Yes, same as you.  net8 with `System.CommandLine.DragonFruit 0.4.0-aplha.22272.1` with the same version on the dependencies.  Are you able to debug your code and inspect `rootCommand.Options` at different points?

Comment: Thank you again for your help and patience. I have made an edit with the breakpoints where you can see the creation of the RootCommand object, but strangely, the Handler property is never set, even though I clearly set it in the constructor.

Comment: Very strange.  That is not the same behavior I see, ie, `Handler` is being set to non-null. 
Can you put a breakpoint where you set the `RootCommand.Handler` property and make sure you hit that line?

Comment: can you set a breakpoint inside of the `RootCommand` constructor and make sure your constructor code is being run?  Is it possible you have another `RootCommand` class defined in another namespace/project?

Comment: I can absolutely try. I've included another edit with a link to a clip of me attempting to set multiple breakpoints. I was unable to actually get a breakpoint to work within the constructor. There's also a project link if that would help.

Comment: Steve thank you so much for your help. I have discovered the issue to be a mistyped namespace `Wtns.Me.lib.Commands` was the namespace I had declared in the `RootCommand` class, where it should have been Wtns.Me.Lib.Commands. (capital L) I have no idea what RootCommand I was using. Discovered this by trying to call it by its full name (`Wtns.Me.Lib.Commands.RootCommand`), and vscode saying it didnt exist. The font i use didn't make it obvious this typo was the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My code was referencing the `System.CommandLine.RootCommand` class when calling `new RootCommand()` which I did not know existed, and therefore hadn't considered naming conflicts.

Referring to my RootCommand class by its fully qualified name `Wtns.Me.Lib.Commands.RootCommand` fixed this problem.